# Have constant space between legend entries in an horizontal legend

Tags: r, plot, alignment, legend

My problem is really simple, but I'm struggling to find a solution to it. The following code:

```
layout(mat = matrix(data = c(1,2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE), heights = c(1,0.3))
par(mar = c(0,1,1,1))
plot(0)
plot.new()
legend(x = 'center', legend = c('f', 'foooo', 'foooooo'), fill = c('red', 'blue', 'green'), horiz = TRUE)
```

produces a plot like this one:

[image]

My question is: how can I make sure that there is a constant distance between the legend's entries and that the legend itself is centred in the legend's box?

Ideally, I would like to have the same distance between "f" and the blue square and between the last "o" in "fooo" and the green square. Additionally, the white space on the left of the red square and the white space on the right of the last "o" in "foooooo" should be equal.

Answer (score 0):

You could add spaces before the f, for the red box 6 spaces and for the blue box 2 spaces. Like this:

```
legend(x = 'center', legend = c('      f', '  foooo', 'foooooo'), fill = c('red', 'blue', 'green'), horiz = TRUE)
```